# What does 'fit' mean in 'crying fit'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I just heard about the phrase 'crying fit' or 'crying fits'.  What does the 'fit' mean here?

Comment: A "fit" is something akin to an epileptic seizure (though with no precise definition).  The term has come to be used in an exaggerated sense to mean an emotional outburst of some sort, as when a child "throws a fit" in a store because he can't have the Super Juicy Crunchy cereal he wants.

Comment: Please consider consulting a dictionary for the meaning of a word. In this case, you will immediately have the answer.

Comment: Look in dictionary for answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [fit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fit):

> - a sudden outburst of emotion: *a fit of jealousy*.

(American Heritage Dictionary)

- in this  sense it  means a sudden, usually short and sometimes uncontrollable, burst of emotion. So a crying fit would be a period of time where the person is crying quite intensely.

Answer (score 2):

"Fit" here means a sudden and uncontrollable outburst of emotion.

Comment: Perhaps 'a sudden and uncontrollable burst' of anything e.g. a coughing fit, sneezing fit etc.

Answer (score 2):

In that specific case, it's

> an onset, spell, or period of emotion, feeling, inclination, activity, etc.: a fit of anger; a fit of weeping.

In the general case, it can also be a sudden attack not just of emotion, but of just about anything:

> a sudden, acute attack or manifestation of a disease, especially one marked by convulsions or unconsciousness: a fit of epilepsy.

That definition just speaks of disease, but I've definitely heard "a fit of carelessness" which I wouldn't think really matched either of the above, but does match the general case of "a sudden attack of (insert blank)".

Another word you may find similarly used is "[jag](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jag)," such as a "crying jag," which is *"a period of unrestrained indulgence in an activity; spree; binge"*.

---

Definitions above for "fit" are from the second noun definition on [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fit). "jag" is from the second noun definition there as well.

Answer (score -1):

A crying fit would be uncontrollable crying. You're crying about something and trying to stop, but you can't because every time you try you have to take a deep breath (with the sort of groaning sound) so you can continue to breathe.

Comment: This is close, but this isn't quite equivalent to the (correct) *outburst* understanding given in the other answer.  Children regularly have "crying fits" that magically end as soon as they get what they want: in such cases, the crying was certainly not *uncontrollable*.